# what is this oleaut32.dll?

Tags: c#, .net

we had an error encountered on one of our windows service application, that points to this dll - oleaut32.dll

here's the eventviewer logs

> The description for Event ID 1000 from source .NET Runtime 4.0 Error
>   Reporting cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event
>   is not installed on your local computer or the installation is
>   corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local
>   computer.
>
> If the event originated on another computer, the display information
>   had to be saved with the event.
>
> The following information was included with the event:
>
> ```
> > [our-application].exe
> > 4.0.0.0 5174a88d oleaut32.dll
> > 5.2.3790.4807 4d0fa719 0 0000000000024057
> ```

we are not sure how or why did this happened unexpectedly or what's causing this error. also, we haven't encountered this kind of error before.

our application is using .net framework 4.0 and runs on a windows 2003 server with updated Microsoft security patches.

Comment: Please open a support case via http://support.microsoft.com. When your application itself or any dependencies try to perform OLE automation, that dll is used. You might have hit one of the known issues (Microsoft has several public hot fixes and private ones). Microsoft support can tell you how to resolve it.

Comment: @LexLi - thanks for pointing that, we'll possibly we may hit a known issue or some kind. I've read that there were hot fixes because of its vulnerability.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`oleaut32.dll` it's a library used in Microsoft for OLE technologies; [OLE Automation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OLE_Automation)

You could check [Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/) to see if you find any support.

Another link with alternatives is [this](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/findbyerrormessage/a/oleaut32-dll-not-found-missing-error.htm).

consider this:

> Important: Do not download oleaut32.dll from a "DLL download" website. There are many reasons why downloading a DLL file is a bad idea. If you need a copy of oleaut32.dll, it's best to obtain it from its original, legitimate source.

Comment: These days oleaut32.dll is a system component. It's one of the standard Windows components.

Comment: This MS KB Article might be of interest: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3020338 (Application does not work correctly after you apply update 3006226 in Windows)